# How to get css property of dynamic table created by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**This is javascript code for creating dynamic table it creates a crossword**

```
function generateTable(range) {
    document.write("<table style='border: 1px solid black;'>");
    for (var a = 1; a < 10; a++) {
        document.write("<tr >");
        for (var b = 1; b < 10; b++) {
            if (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0) {
                document.write("<td style='border: 1px solid black;'><button style='width:50px; height:50px; background-color:black'></button></td>");
            } else {
                document.write("<td style='border: 1px solid black;'><button style='width:50px; height:50px; background-color:white' ></button></td>");
            }
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
}
```

**output is something like this**
[image]

**I want to count the n of black boxes with different function I have tried with getelementsbytagname() but it's not working please help me with this**

Comment: Start using CSS classes and you'll find your task much easier.

Comment: Can you post full example of your code.

Comment: I have already defined the class but it is not generating table  if I define the class inside td tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use CSS for displaying purpose. 
To this, you will have to add class to each of the `button`.

```js
function generateTable(range) {
  document.write("<table>");
  for (var a = 1; a < range; a++) {
    document.write("<tr >");
    for (var b = 1; b < range; b++) {
      if (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0) {
        document.write("<td ><button class='black'></button></td>");


      } else {
        document.write("<td ><button class='white'></button></td>");
      }
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
  }
  document.write("</table>");
}
generateTable(10);

console.log("total Black " + document.getElementsByClassName("black").length); //<-- count of black
console.log("total white " + document.getElementsByClassName("white").length); //<-- count of white
//using query selector
console.log("total Black " + document.querySelectorAll(".black").length); //<-- count of black
console.log("total white " + document.querySelectorAll(".white").length); //<-- count of white
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button.black {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

button.white {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively to `document.querySelectorAll()` you can also use `document.getElementsByClassName("black")`

Comment: one more help please on clicking on white button how can I make it black?

Comment: You will have to add a click event to that button and change the class.

Comment: @NITISH the following code is one possibility to do this: [see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahendwh2/xsr64s68/)

Comment: can I give each cell an index? Ex 1st (11) second(12) I  have tried contacting  a and b from both the loops and passing it as id but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Although querying by style properties is possible, I think you may be better off creating the back boxes using a class instead on inline styles like so:

```
document.write("<td style='border: 1px solid black;'><button style='box box-black'></button></td>");
```

Adding the required CSS:

```
.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

.box-black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

And then simply querying the class you want:

```
const blackBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box-black').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function generateTable()
{

document.write("<table style='border: 1px solid black;'>");
for (var a=1; a <10; a++) {
document.write("<tr >");
for(var b=1; b<10; b++) {
if(a%2==0 && b%2==0 )
{
document.write("<td style='border: 1px solid black;'><button id='blk' style='width:50px; height:50px; background-color:black'></button></td>");


}
else
{
document.write("<td style='border: 1px solid black;'><button style='width:50px; height:50px; background-color:white' ></button></td>");
}

}
document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
console.log("BlackBox :"+ document.querySelectorAll('#blk').length)
}

generateTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for count number of black box. You can get elements by tag name. You can get it by className which is the best way you can easily get count.

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("Button");
var count=0;
    for(var k=0;k<list.length;k++)
    {
        if(list[k].style.backgroundColor=='red')
            count++;
    }
console.log("number of black box--",count);
```

Answer (score 0):

The advice to change to CSS is great, but if you had reason to leave it as is and still wanted to count, here you go:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON");
var whites = 0, blacks=0;
for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
    color = list[i].style.backgroundColor;
    if (color == 'white') whites++;
    else if (color == 'black') blacks++;

    // to add an index: 
    // list[i].setAttribute('data-index',i+10);
}

console.log('w:'+whites+", b:"+blacks);
```

References: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

Comment: can I give each cell an index? Ex 1st cell (11) second cell(12) I have tried contacting a and b from both the loops and passing it as id but it's not working

Comment: Sure. Is the index the same, or is it an index unique for each color?

Comment: I'll add a comment above to show how to add an index to each button. The cells would be by "td" of course, so the code would have to call getElementsByTagName("TD") instead.